# How to be sure that I harvest power?

Tags: power, power-electronics, energy, energy-harvesting

I am working with an electrochemical device which (I guess) harvests power. How can I be sure that I harvest power ?

My first idea was to plug a battery on my system. The problem is that my device products mW with a open circuit voltage of 600 mV, so it's impossible to load a battery by just plugging.

My second was to put a resistor in water and to study the temperature difference to follow the increasing but I guess this temperature gap is too small.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: make it power an LED?

Comment: ..and if it does have enough oomph do  that use a joule thief circuit.

Comment: Just put something like a 1k resistor at the output and measure the voltage across it. Eventually integrate the results.

Comment: Your reluctance to more fully specify the electrical nature of your electrochemical device doesn't help us much. Is it AC? DC? Linear? When it is not generating power, what impedance might it be?....

Answer (score 2):

View the output with an oscilloscope. Measure the voltage vs. movement. Put a load resistor across the output and measure the voltage/current to determine how much power it actually produces.

Your question seems very confused if you are only guessing that it "harvests power". Perhaps you would be better to positively identify what it is and how it works before trying to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Crowley offers a first step - monitor your source with a voltage-measuring device with and without a load resistor. It seems that your charging source might be able to provide charging current to a battery. Substitute a super capacitor instead - these are very high capacitance, low voltage devices.
[image: one Farad supercapacitor]

You can measure the time taken to charge this capacitor from zero volts to a known voltage (like 200mV for example). From this you can either calculate current (I=C * time/0.2) or calculate joules (C * .04/2).
These big capacitors make it easy to measure time with a stopwatch, but suffer from non-ideal characteristics like poor tolerance, dielectric absorption. You could substitute a better-quality capacitor, like a polypropylene or polycarbonate capacitor. Since you likely won't find one with larger capacitance than 10uF, your time measurement must have far higher accuracy and resolution - too fast to be done by hand with a stopwatch.

### Charge-and-dump

Use the smaller-value high quality capacitor with some electronics for a better measurement system that can proceed continuously. The same process (charge capacitor to a known voltage with your charging source) is used, but upon reaching the target voltage level, dump the capacitor's charge quickly to zero volts, then release to charge again, repeatedly. You have now an oscillator whose frequency is nearly proportional to the charging current. A standard LMC555 bistable oscillator might require significant modification to work this way.

Charge-and-dump has a few potential problems:
1) the charging source is short-circuited momentarily while the capacitor is quickly discharged - some charging sources may object to this treatment.
2) A non-linear charging source (like a solar cell) spends much of its time providing charging current into a low-voltage load. This gives you overly-optimistic charging results (compared with charging a load up near the 600mV top end).
3) A poor charging source that is leaky will tend to charge the capacitor at a slower rate, since some of its current is consumed internally. That's fine, but if leakage current is greater than capacitor charging current, the oscillator fails to oscillate. Or if leakage doesn't allow the capacitor to charge to its trigger voltage, the oscillator fails to oscillate. Such a charging source is pretty much useless unless additional energy harvesting electronics blocks the leakage process from discharging the energy storage element (capacitor in this case).